# React native rotateY

Tags: reactjs, react-native, animation, css-animations

Why when I add rotateY to a transform, the item changes position? It seems to be rotating, but position that changes too.

Am I missing something please? How can I make element spin in one place? Thanks

```
<View
  style={{
    transform: [
      {
        rotateY: '180deg'
      }
    ]
  }}
>
  <Coin count={4} />
</View>
```

Comment: I think it is happening due to width and height of the element.

Comment: You are right - I was rotating the container which was really wide rather then the item. Thank you!